# cowsay alternative

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, cowsay

Can anyone tell me if there is an alternative to the `cowsay` command that prints dinosaurs instead of cows or other things? I tried with the `-f` flag, but I always have to change files to print different ones.

I looked here looking for alternatives to cowsay, but nothing: https://www.producthunt.com/alternatives/cowsay-ascii-generator

Thank you

Comment: This is more of a [Super User](https://superuser.com/) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two ways/method to do what you want:

- dinosay

It's on [github](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/dinosay) and [pip](https://pypi.org/project/dinosay/), and while it's not written in Perl (as the original version is) *it does* implement by default what you want (which are dinosaurs instead of cows)

- Use custom ascii art with cowsay

This is supported by default by cowsay, in the form of "cowfile". This takes the form of a Perl snippet, and is described succinctly in [the `cowsay` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/cowsay.6#COWFILE_FORMAT).

That being said, most repos where you installed cowsay should provide you with one or two dinosaurs.

Comment: example with cowsay: `cowsay -f stegosaurus Hello World`. More here: `/usr/share/cowsay/cows/`

Comment: on mac: `/opt/local/share/cowsay/cows`